# Send messages every 24 hours from a list discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How would I make my Discord Bot send a message every 24 hours with a message from a list of messages, in order.

The code for my bot has been attached.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  var testChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '905594922768429077');
  
  
  console.log('I am connected !'); 

  setInterval(() => {
    testChannel.send();
  }, 24 hour time here );
});

client.login('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your messages in an array, every day a variable will be incremented to get the next message by array index.

```js
const messages = ['day 1', 'day 2', 'day 3'];
var index = 0;

client.on('ready', () => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '905594922768429077');

  setInterval(() => {
    channel.send({ content: messages[index] });
    index = index > messages.length - 2 ? 0 : index + 1;
  }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // in milliseconds
});
```